# ESLint rule for whitespace before single-line inline comment

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm looking for something that I thought would be standard in ESLint rules but somehow can't find in the [list of rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

There is the `spaced-comment` rule that enforces a space immediately **after** the opening // of single-line comment.

I would like to enforce a white space immediately **before** an inline comment.

```
test(); // This would be allowed
test();// This wouldn't be
```

Is there a rule I'm not seeing for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as the other answer mentions, **ESLint** does not have a rule for requiring space before the double fwd slashed **<kbd>//</kbd>** at the beginning of a line comment. only allows you to set the amount of spaces after the double fwd slashes: **`//`**. **ESLint** v8.0 is a really exciting update, therefore I have read what it includes, and I know that it doesn't include a space before a comment, consequently, it would be reasonable to assume that **ESLint** leaves this small tidbit up to formatters, or the user, if that user does not use a formatter.

---

##### There are two solutions, but neither include an ESLint rule:

- The first is extremely obvious, but more common than I once thought — Lint your code then format your code manually using your mouse and eyeballs.
- The second is is probably the most popular option: use **Prettier**, __FYI: You Don't Need A Plugin for This". Prettier is biased, and spaces bore a inline comment starts is an unchangeable part of the Prettier Style Guide. Many people avoid prettier, because it use to be an extremely arduous task to add both **ESLint** & **Prettier** into the same project and achieving conflictless harmony between the two ECMAScript tools, however, the contemporary configuration required for the two is far easier to setup because of new extensions & plugins that have been created. If you use VSCode, you just need to install the ESLint & Prettier-ESLint extensions, plus you need to NPM install ESLint & Prettier as development environment extensions.

---

###### > *"The Above is probably not exactly what you were looking for, but I felt it was worth mentioning it, because even if you already were aware of all I wrote, at least it confirms that where you stand, is where the Linter you are using also stands."*

###### Its important to note that a linter is not a formatter, and visa versa, this is why people use both.

---